# How concat with JSF code in id attribute on XHTML?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, xhtml, concatenation

I am working with JSF 2.2 and I would like to build dynamic forms with jsf; this is my code:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <ui:repeat value="#{bean.list}" var="object">
        <h:panelGroup id="something#{object.id}">
            <h:commandButton value="update" action="#{bean.doSomething}">
                <f:ajax render="another#{object.id}" execute ="something#{object.id}"/>
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup id="another#{object.id}">
             <!--....-->
        </h:panelGroup>
    </ui:repeat>
</h:form>
```

It not working. I checked html generated and `something#{object.id}` is represented as :myForm:j_idt93:0:something, without `object.id`. For this reason not working.

I  changed the `h:form` into `ui:repeat` and this solution working, but as I need update `another#{object.id}`, with `h:form` I can't point which `another`  update.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you really saying that it doesn't work when you remove all those unnecessary `#{object.id}` suffixes from the ID attributes? You don't need those at all. Just use `id="something"` `render="another" execute="something"` `id="another"` the usual way. If that doesn't work for some reason, then the problem is caused elsewhere and you need to post a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you!. I used <c:forEach...> and all was perfect.